# Where is my "data" Ajax option in Razor syntax?

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

In the documentation https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxoptions%28v=vs.118%29.aspx I can't find anything that is the equivalent of the `data` parameter in something like

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("AutoLocate")',
    type: 'GET',
    data: postData,
    success: function(result) {
        // process the results from the controller
    }
});
```

Using Razor syntax for a form, e.g.

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("GenerateMasterLink", "SurfaceAssets", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "masterLinkHolder" })) { ... }
```

how do I tell it that I want a JavaScript variable, say,

```
var str = "here's a string, bro!";
```

to be passed in to the corresponding controller

```
public ActionResult GenerateMasterLink (string str)
{
    ...
}
```

??????

Comment: The "data" variable is the form data itself.  If you want to add more data, create one or more hidden fields in the form.  Those fields will be bound to the model that you are POSTing back to the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this.

```
$.ajax({
url: '@Url.Action("AutoLocate")',
type: 'GET',
data: str,
success: function(result) {
    // process the results from the controller
}
});
```

and in controller

```
public ActionResult GenerateMasterLink (string str)
{
...
}
```

If you have more than one parameter then

```
$.ajax({
url: '@Url.Action("AutoLocate")',
type: 'GET',
data: {id: 12,name:'Name'},
success: function(result) {
    // process the results from the controller
}
});

public ActionResult GenerateMasterLink (int id,string name)
{
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass form data into the action GenerateMasterLink using a C# type you create in your server code with one property for each of the properties in your javascript object. It might looks something like this:

```
public class FormData 
{
    public int PropertyName1 { get; set; }
    public string PropertyName2 { get; set; }
}

public ActionResult GenerateMasterLink (FormData form)
{
   ...
}
```

Make sure the data being sent is valid JSON (use JSON.stringify() in JavaScript to convert a JavaScript object to JSON). Also, you can get the value into your view using the ViewBag (or model). Here's how you'd set it in the ViewBag:

```
public ActionResult GenerateMasterLink (FormData form)
{
   ViewBag.SomeNameOfYourChoosing = form.PropertyName1;
   return View();
}
```

Then in the Razor:

```
@ViewBag.SomeNameOfYourChoosing
```

Comment: For more, see the MSDN documentation here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controllerbase.viewbag%28v=vs.118%29.aspx